# Unity - Stay Within Screen Bounds

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, screen, physics, bounds

I have been making a top down 2d game and have come across a small issue. I need the player to stay within the screen bounds at all times. I have seen people with this problem before and have tried their solutions however none of them have worked with my game. This is because my player character uses physics to move around. This is what I have inside my FixedUpdate function:

```
    minScreenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    maxScreenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0));

    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minScreenBounds.x + 1, maxScreenBounds.x - 1), Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minScreenBounds.y + 1, maxScreenBounds.y - 1), transform.position.z);
```

If anyone knows how to fix this I would much appreciate it if you could tell me how.

Many Thanks,

Tommy

Comment: You need to provide more details. help us to help you. a script and where could be the problem is great. we don't know details as you are on your project.

Comment: Ok I will add the script...

Answer (score 1):

Make **4 [kinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-isKinematic.html) [`Rigidbody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) to the screen edges**, like below (green colliders), and manage their scale / position for your need.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The problem with that approach is that other GameObjects would collide with the screen bounds too. I need something that limits only the player from leaving the screen.

Comment: Well, mask collision with layers. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html I have a feeling that you should read more on the topic in general. Take a look at https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials

Comment: Looking at your code, it would be better use `MovePosition`, and `MoveRotation` on `Rigidbody2D` instead manipulating transform directly.